# Can I delete certain folders on my computer?

Tags: windows

I recently wanted to clean up some space in my C drive, and I found the following folders taking up considerable amounts of space, but I am not sure if it will be safe to delete them:

1. `C:/users/public/L001` - 40.7GB
2. `C:/users/{name}/Appdata` - 7.5GB
3. `C:/windows/winsxs` - 14.5GB
4. `C:/pagefile.sys` - 14.6GB

As for the first folder, I can't even find any reference to it on the internet. So just to provide some information about it: it contains 1,88,841 files. All are extensionless files and are named as "year_*time*". For example: `2012-09-02_08-45-50`

Comment: The `AppData` folder is important because it contains a lot of your applications' data. Try exploring its contents; you should find that they're organised into folders for each software manufacturer or program. You can check the sizes of each of the contained folders and decide what to do on a per-application basis. You might decide to uninstall some of the applications and delete their corresponding folders if you're happy to lose your configuration in them.

Comment: The first one definitely seems worth checking out. The other folders are standard, but that one looks odd. If the file creation/modification times indicate they're still being created or updated regularly, perhaps you could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the computer's activity to determine which program is using it.

Comment: [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2795190) or [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/) might help regarding `WinSxS`.

Comment: I think `pagefile.sys` is used as virtual memory. See [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/change-virtual-memory-size) to reduce its size. I think 14.6GB is way too much, but it really depends on how you use the computer. This is a large topic worth looking into if you want to make a more informed decision about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\pagefile.sys` is created by Windows usually in direct correlation to your RAM installed. It is used by the system to keep a copy of what is in RAM if the computer needs to transfer it immediately to a file. Thus, if you had 12GB of RAM installed, you can usually expect the pagefile to be around the 12GB mark.

Mostly, it is used as a swap, when your system needs to swap-in or swap-out data from the RAM *(which is where the data is stored by the application/s running)* and then put the data for application which might be minimised for a long time or put into the background as you run other applications.

`Hibernation.sys` is another file that is used when your system needs to transfer everything from the RAM to the hard disk whilst it is in hibernation. The problem with this though, is Windows sometimes has trouble getting out of hibernation mode and resumes operation. You did not mention this file, but for anyone else reading, to disable this problem *(especially with laptops)* open the **Command Prompt** by right-clicking on it and selecting **"Run As Administrator"** then type:

```
C:\>powercfg -h off
```

As for the `pagefile.sys`you can generally make it smaller, but not remove it all together. If you are concerned with this file, follow the following steps. I would however advise you to be careful in doing this, as it may affect the overall performance of your computer!

1. Go to Control Panel
2. System
3. Advanced System Settings
4. Performance Settings
5. Advanced
6. Virtual Memory
7. Set it to "custom size" and select a size (in MB)

If you think you don't need it, you can disable it here too. If you launch a few applications simultaneously or run a resource intensive game, you might get an **"Out Of Memory"** error. If this is the case, just increase the file size and restart.

My recommendation is to not have this any smaller than 10% of your overall RAM. Keeping in mind however, that ram is not **1000MB** but rather **1024MB** per **GB**.

So, for each GB on your system, multiply this by 1024.  If you have a 4GB system, you would use 10% like this:

```
4 * 1024 = 4096
4096 / 10 = 409.6
```

So, for a 4GB system, I would allocate a minimum of 410MB *(round up to the nearest whole number)*.

---

`C:/users/public/L001 - 40.7 gb` <- this concerns me as to ask this it generally would indicate that you are unsure of the user that this folder concerns.

To ensure that none of your users require this folder, might I suggest doing the following:

1. Log into each user on your system
2. Open a **Command Prompt**
3. Type `CD %HOMEPATH%` from the window and press enter

Your **Command Prompt** will change from something like this:

```
Microsoft Windows Version [6.xxxx.xxxx]
(c) 2011 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

C:\>
```

to something like this:

```
Microsoft Windows Version [6.xxxx.xxxx]
(c) 2011 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

C:\>CD %HOMEPATH%

C:\Users\John>
```

This would indicate to me *(if your username is John for example)* that your home directory for this user is `C:\Users\John` and not related to that folder above mentioned.  It is not safe to assume that even if you did this on EVERY USER on your computer and none matched, that it would still be safe to delete, but it gives you a clear indication that no logged on users that you use, make direct use of this folder.

UPDATE:

All folders in `C:\Users\Public` are considered "public" folders, meaning they can or have been used as a central place to put files between users on the computer, or across a network. [This article](http://windows.about.com/od/organizingyourstuff/f/what_is_public_folder.htm) doesn't say much, but it will give you a very brief overview. I would just look into it, if you're sure it's all crap, just delete it.

---

`C:/users/{name}/Appdata - 7.5 gb`

Try to not delete this folder. Maybe uninstall applications you don't need. This is where applications will store files for each user that have access to those applications.

If you were going to install **Microsoft Outlook** and you and your partner had each their own account, in this directory on his/her account would be the profiles and settings for **Microsoft Outlook** which is how you can keep your own settings in each application separate.

**NOTE:** This does not apply to ALL applications - e.g. games

---

`C:/windows/winsxs - 14.5 gb`

I am going to assume you use Windows 7 from having this folder. It requires a technical explanation that is not only unnecessary, but better done by the experts. In short - **DO NOT DELETE THIS**.

See this [article regarding WinSxS folder](http://blogs.technet.com/askcore/archive/2008/09/17/what-is-the-winsxs-directory-in-windows-2008-and-windows-vista-and-why-is-it-so-large.aspx). It doesn't mention Windows 7, but it is exactly the same reason why you cannot delete it.

Comment: The size of the first folder has now increased to 40.7 gb containing 1,89,004 Files now. I posted this question on another stack exchange site by mistake. One person mentioned existence of a virus and suggested to delete by booting into safe mode and deleting it.Any clue ?

Comment: That is quite possible. Go to this Microsoft KB article and it will show you how to boot into Safe Mode http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/safe-mode-f8-doesnt-work/

Comment: Just remember to turn it off again once you've gone into Safe Mode and deleted that folder. The other option is to press F8 repeatedly when the computer loads and select `Safe Mode` from the list. You won't need networking option. Once you've finished, just restart your computer.

Answer (score 2):

To directly address your questions:

1. Probably safe to delete as far as Windows' operation is concerned, but it's better to find out what it actually is there for. Perhaps a user or application uses that.
2. Probably a bad idea to delete this because it stores data used by the applications on the computer.
3. Probably a bad idea to delete this because it's probably depended on by various applications.
4. Probably safe to disable, but it might occasionally cause problems depending on your use.

Comment: IIRC you could always set windows to manage the space for the pagefile automatically (which is a good idea), set it to a smaller manually set size (not too hot on that) or move it to another drive (though this disables crashdumps).

Answer (score 0):

2) There is a lot of things safe to delete in appdata\local and appdata\locallow, because these folders are not saved to server when you logoff from the computer in the roaming profile environment, so they are not present on the next pc you would login. Applications usually store cache and various temp data there. See what Rainer says here
http://pcreview.co.uk/forums/safe-delete-appdata-local-t3461082.html
Basically everything named cache or temp can be deleted..